# Issue deserializing a date represented as a string in document from Cosmos DB

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I currently have a C# application that queries Cosmos DB. In the database everything is stored as strings. When I query the container for the document and pull out the information it looks like the deserialization process is treating it like a date and its applying the Date Time Offset. Strange part is this process of querying the DB never converts it to a date? I would like it to just pass through  the app as its stored in Cosmos.

Here is the document shape in Cosmos:

```
{
   "id": "uniqueId",
   "MyDate" : "2021-07-24T23:59:00+0000"
}
```

Here is the code that connects to CosmosDB

```
using(var client = new CosmosClient("EndPoint","Key")
{
      string sqlQueryText = "Select * From c Where .... ";
      QueryDefinition querySQL = new QueryDefination(sqlQueryText);
      var container = client.GetContainer("databaseId", "ContainerId");
      var iii = container.GetItemQueryIterator<Document>(querySQL);
      
      var myList = new List<Document>();

      while(iii.HasMoreResults)
      {
          FeedResponse<Document> currentRS = iii.ReadNextAsync().Result;

          foreach(Document doc in currentRS)
          {
              myList.Add(doc);
          }
      }
}
```

Here is the Output of the this process in C#, By output I mean if you look at the myList Object and inspect the Mydate Property you will see this string below.

```
"07/24/2021 19:59:00"
```

which is the date & time with the date time offset.

How do I prevent this?

This application should just pass the string straight through with no regard for "Real Type".

I would just like to get "2021-07-24T23:59:00+0000"

Comment: What is the `Document` type in your code? If you want to bind the value as a string, created a model class that includes a string property for `MyDate`

Comment: Document -> (Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Document)  Represents a document in the Cosmos DB Service.   It is a structured JSON document. There is no set schema and there can be any number of custom properties.   This was used so that its Generic  because the method just grabs documents based on a key and they are ever changing.

Comment: OK. Please include the code that produces the output you show?

Comment: I already did in the original post.  if you inspect the object in mylist and look at the MyDate Property you will see the output in the immedieate window.

Comment: I'd suggest following the samples. If you don't want to use a model class, you could deserialize to `dynamic` instead from raw stream. This avoids anything getting in the way of your desired treatment of raw values. https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/Queries/Program.cs

Comment: `Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Document` is internal so the above code does not compile for me. The issue is probably due to this anyway https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/862 so you'll need to look for a way to override the annoying default

Comment: Using a model class do the same conversion too. The solution in our team was to make `document.ToString()` and deserialize it using `JsonConvert` back to our model class. Now I'm looking how to avoid this double serialization.